# How can i pop a value with key from local state?

Tags: reactjs

I have a local state as object:

```
selectedDates = {};
```

When i click on icons I am getting ID´s in my local state as object `key, value` pair.

```
    // We "open" the value to extract the relevant informations
    const [key, value] = calendarIconId.split("=");

    // Add the new value inside of the object
    this.state.selectedDatesTemp[key] = value;

    // Turn the object into an array, we gotta rebuild the values
    const date = Object.keys(this.state.selectedDatesTemp).map(
        x => `${x}=${this.state.selectedDatesTemp[x]}`
    );
```

How can i delete an object from the local state?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Can you provide some example of expected result and current result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `delete` to achieve it:

```js
const { selectedDatesTemp } = this.state;
delete selectedDatesTemp[key];
```